# jquery simplify statements

Tags: jquery

Say I have the following, is there a way to chain them together, or simplify them in an way?

```
var initialTab = $('#navigation li#red');
initialTab.siblings().removeClass('on').find('ul').fadeOut(1000);
initialTab.addClass('on').find('ul').fadeIn(1000);
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the HTML? And what's supposed to happen when? What should get/lose the on-class, fade out/in, etc?

Comment: Nick Craver's solution is technically correct, but for the record I prefer what you've done for readability. By naming the variable, it's easy to see at a glance that you're removing 'on' from adjacent tabs and hiding them, while adding 'on' from the "initial tab" and showing it. That one name makes all the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain it, like this:

```
$('#red').addClass('on').find('ul').fadeIn(1000)
   .end().siblings().removeClass('on').find('ul').fadeOut(1000);
```

An ID must be unique, so just `#red` will suffice here, and though [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) takes the chain the the `<ul>` descendants, [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) takes it back to the `#red` element so we can use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) on that.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to simplify those statements? They work on different elements and have different meanings. Chaining it further would make it harder both to understand and read.

But, if you really want to:

```
var initialTab = $('#navigation li#red');
initialTab.addClass('on').find('ul').fadeIn(1000).end()
   .siblings().removeClass('on').find('ul').fadeOut(1000);
```